# How to call Constants Declared in Metadata Of substrate Node

Tags: substrate, parity, polkadot, polkadot-js, centrifuge

I am using this library https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client where we fetch Latest Metadata via this call in my gloang code `api.RPC.State.GetMetadataLatest()`. This will return me metaData result for the connected substrate node from the go-substrate-rpc-client library.

I am able to fetch the storage, calls and events for any given palette the same can be achieved for the following like this,

1. **Storage** ==> `key, err = types.CreateStorageKey(meta, "System", "Account", signature.TestKeyringPairAlice.PublicKey, nil)`
2. **Calls** ==> `c, err := types.NewCall(meta, "Balances.transfer", bob, types.NewUCompactFromUInt(1000))`
3. **Events** ==> `sub, err := api.RPC.Author.SubmitAndWatchExtrinsic(ext)`

But I`m unable to find a way to fetch Constants that are declared in MetaData using go-substrate-rpc.

Balances Palette contains a constant **ExistentialDeposit** whose value to retrieved via **golang** api.

Comment: I see that they have [a development support channel on their discord](https://discord.com/invite/yEzyUq5gxF) I tihnk it would be best answered by Centrifuge, as it's their product.

Comment: please do report back an answer here for the community looking if you get one!